# How to simulate microsoft surface dial event?

Tags: c#

Microsoft has introduced a new peripheral called Surface Dial. I know there are ways to simulate mouse and keyboard events but I can't find any api to simulate Surface Dial event. Basically, I want to do things like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> would trigger counterclockwise rotation event.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/windows-wheel-interactions and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Input.RadialController. Google search was "Surface dial interface"

Comment: @scrappedcola i want to simulate not listen to dial events

Comment: @user1865027 You're probably going to have to make your own wrapper. One version where it uses the RadialController and one where it is your own simulated implementation. Luckily there is the `IRadialController` you can use.

Comment: @TyCobb do you have more detail example?

Comment: @user1865027 No, I don't currently have that SDK accessible. I am merely going off of the pages scrappedcola presented. Basically, create class, implement `IRadialController` and then fill in the blanks with hooks for you to simulate.

Comment: Id love to have the radial menu pop up when pressing my mouse scrollwheel,. it should be possible - can't find anyone that has created it yet though.